# Content assist failure for nested class constructors in Eclipse Neon.2

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon, content-assist

If I want to create a new class that is a static nested class, **content assist fails to match the constructor**, and this is very unconvenient.

How to configure content assist to match static nested classes' constructors like this TifImageSource?

```
public class ImageSources {


public static class TifImageSource extends ImageSource {
    public TifImageSource(Provider<InputStream> inputStreamProvider) {
        super(inputStreamProvider, "tif");
    }
}

public static class ImageSource {
   ....
}
```

}

This **not works** (with new keyword):

[image]

This **works** (but unconvenient!):

[image]

Comment: Since an "inner class" in Java by definition is a nested class that is not declared `static`, there is no such thing in Java as an "inner static class".

Comment: Thanks, corrected question.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the rules of Java syntax instead of fighting them.

Start with `new ImageSources` or `new ImageS` plus content assistance.

Add a period.

```
new ImageSources.
```

Then start typing the nested class name (it's not an inner class or the syntax would be different).

```
new ImageSources.TifIm
```

Content assistance should then be able to cue you for

```
new ImageSources.TifImageSource(...)
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but java allows to import the outer class (ImageSources). And yes it is possible to extract them from the outer to separate files but my point is maybe it can be good for readability to group similar purpose classes to an outer class like this, and in client code, it is not probably better to see outer class prefix at all use places, but this can be a point of discussion.

Comment: You can use `import static` for the nested type, which I think and hope addresses your comment, but I am not sure if I understood it right.

Comment: Don't need to be static. This simply works: import com.multipasol.***.common.ImageSources.TifImageSource;

Comment: You should not nest types "for readability". Doing so is virtually certain to defeat that stated purpose. Use nested and inner classes judiciously as the logic of the model dictates. Irrational type structures harm both readability and your program.